# Count similar values from one column in Business Objects

Tags: count, business-objects

I'm using Webi 12.2.
How can i count similar values from one column and put the value in the another.

Sth like this (column 'Shape' is queried from DB):

```
Count  |  Shape
----------------------
2      |  Triangle
3      |  Circle
3      |  Circle
1      |  Star
2      |  Triangle
3      |  Circle
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

To do this, I would create a new variable in the report.  That variable would count based upon the type.  The variable can then be made into a new column.